# how do I forward *only* http proxy across vlans?

Tags: linux, router, iptables

My router has two bridges, br0 and br1.  I'm sharing wifi access, and the guest subnet will be 192.168.2.x.  The home subnet will be 192.168.1.x.

I want all traffic destined for port 80 from the guest net to forward to a proxy port on a box on the home network.  That's the *only* traffic I want to cross the bridges.  How do I set this up with iptables on the router?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming br0 is the home net, and br1 the guest one:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100 # ip of the proxy box
```

To set up the redirection, then

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

(check if it is not already there) to allow already established connections, it simplifies the rules,

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state NEW -i br1 -o br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -d 192.168.1.100 -j ACCEPT
```

Allow connections from the guest net to the proxy box (this gets processed after the DNAT)

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i br1 -o br0 -j DROP
```

Forbid all other traffic between the bridges.

Your device is probably already configured as a router, but if not, you may need to enable forwarding too:

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```